# After 23.04 Upgrade, I have a half-configured kernel

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

So, I upgraded to 23.04 and I have an issue with apt upgrade where it will say that 4 packages will be "not fully installed or removed". It then proceeds to attempt to configure the kernel I'm currently running, which is 6.2.0-20-generic.

It appears that dpkg is failing due to some dependency, but I'm unsure what it is, exactly. Please see the error log below. There is more after what I paste, but the other packages obviously fail due to the failure to configure the first package. I have researched the issue, but I'm not totally sure what to do.

I have tried uninstalling the kernel, but apt fails at this.

```
root@5DC:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease [267 kB]                
Hit:3 https://packages.matrix.org/debian focal InRelease                       
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]       
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://packagecloud.io/crowdsec/crowdsec/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 357 kB in 1s (377 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@5DC:/# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.2.0-20-gen
eric/build/include KVERSION=6.2.0-20-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.12.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subpr
ocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Processing triggers for linu
x-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.2.0-20-gen
eric/build/include KVERSION=6.2.0-20-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.12.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encoun
tered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Probably best to remove the EVDI first:  https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi as it states that "Compatibility with distributions other than Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 LTS is not verified. Please let us know if you make it work on other distros - pull requests are welcome!"

Comment: I edited the post as the first commenter suggested. I will try to remove the DisplayLink driver and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: SOLVED, thank you Terrance. I would not have known that EVDI was related to DisplayLink without your help.

Comment: We use a Q&A format here. Please don't add "SOLVED" to your question. I have rolled back your recent edit. Here is the [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1464455/4). We encourage you to post an *answer* if you have a solution. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, and had to completely remove all dkms modules.

```
$ dkms status
```

Will show you the modules. Remove them with:

```
dkms remove --all modulename
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the DisplayLink evdi with the command `sudo displaylink-installer uninstall`

Comment: It would be nice is you explained why to do this.